# Отключить быстрое редактирование текста в консоли C++

Tags: c++, winapi, консоль

Я пытаюсь отключить режим быстрого редактирования в консоли, так как при этом приостанавливается программа. Я уже смотрел документацию и пробовал это:

```cpp
DWORD prevConsoleMode;
GetConsoleMode(handle, &prevConsoleMode);
SetConsoleMode(handle, prevConsoleMode & ~ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE);
```

```cpp
SetConsoleMode(handle, ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS | (prevConsoleMode & ~ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE));
```

```cpp
SetConsoleMode(handle, prevConsoleMode & ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS);
```

```cpp
SetConsoleMode(handle, prevConsoleMode & (~ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE  | ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS ));
```

Но не один из способов не сработал.

Comment: Обе функции возвращают 1

Comment: В случае ошибки обе функции должны возвращать 0. Ненулевое значение означает успешное выполнение.

Answer (score 1):

Включение:

```
SetConsoleMode(handle, prevConsoleMode | ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS | ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE);
```

Выключение:

```
SetConsoleMode(handle, prevConsoleMode | ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS);
```

Всё как и написано в документации:

> To enable this mode, use ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE |
>   ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS. **To disable this mode, use ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS
>   without this flag**.